# How to make an onClick of one object trigger a new intent from a gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I was wondering how to start an intent to open a new activity, when the user has clicked one of the objects inside the gridview. Oh and also if this changes anything, the gridview has a searchview where it filters out results.

Mainactivity

```
GridView gv;
SearchView sv;

String[] Champions = {"Aatrox", "Ahri", "Akali"};
int[] Champimgs = {R.drawable.aatrox_square_0, R.drawable.ahri_square_0, R.drawable.akali_square_0};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);


    final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, this.getChampions());
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);


    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

            return false;
        }
    });


}

private ArrayList<Champions> getChampions() {
    ArrayList<Champions> champions = new ArrayList<Champions>();
    Champions p;

    for (int i = 0; i < Champions.length; i++) {
        p = new Champions(Champions[i], Champimgs[i]);
        champions.add(p);
    }
    return champions;
}
```

}

Champions

```
public Champions(String Champion, int Champimg) {

    this.Champimg=Champimg;
    this.Champion=Champion;}

    public String getChampion() {
        return Champion;
    }

    public int getChampimg() {
        return Champimg;
    }

    public void setChampion(String champion) {
    Champion = champion;
    }

    public void setChampimg(int champimg) {
    Champimg = champimg;
    }
```

}

Adapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Champion.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Champion.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return Champion.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model, null);
    }
    TextView nameTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    nameTxt.setText(Champion.get(position).getChampion());
    img.setImageResource(Champion.get(position).getChampimg());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if (filter == null)
    {
        filter=new CustomFiler();
    }
    return filter;
}

class CustomFiler extends Filter
{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
        {
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

            ArrayList<Champions> filters = new ArrayList<Champions>();

            for(int i = 0;i<filterlist.size();i++){

                if (filterlist.get(i).getChampion().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                Champions p= new Champions (filterlist.get(i).getChampion(),filterlist.get(i).getChampimg());
                    filters.add(p);
            }
        }
            results.count=filters.size();
            results.values=filters;
        }else{
            results.count=filterlist.size();
            results.values=filterlist;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        Champion = (ArrayList<Champions>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you slightly overcomplicate things in your adapter. `Champion.indexOf(getItem(position))` == `position`. I'd try adding a clicklistener (`gv.setOnItemClickListener(...)`), http://android--code.blogspot.de/2015/08/android-gridview-onitemclicklistener.html - `Champions selectedItem = (Champions) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` if you want to get the item, and starting activities is the [usual syntax](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added this to fix it;

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch( position )
            {
                case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ahri.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity);
                    break;

                case 1:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Aatrox.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity2);
                    break;

            }
```

Comment: If you need to update your post, please use the "edit" button at the bottom of the post instead of using the answer box to make changes.

Comment: sure but i was answering my own question once i found out how to do it

Comment: OK but before your recent edit (after my comment) it didn't look like you were fixing anything at all and posting as an answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Also, if that solves your problem, explain why it solves it, how it works and mark it as the answer. Just like if you were trying to help another person, someone who read this may not know why this is the solution he needs.